ACC Acount Admin API users:import endpoint returns 500
I am trying to call the users:import endpoint as described in this ACC doc ACC Create Projects but I keep receiving the following 500 response even after I have all of the previous endpoint calls working and have confirmed that the project status is active, that the admin has the correct permissions, the configured app has the correct permissions, and the two-legged token has the necessary scopes and has been working correctly. That link to that doc above also has a link to the doc for the users:import endpoint, but that link returns a 404 currently. Sensitive values have been replaced with {} placeholders:
Status Code: 500
Response Headers: {'Server': 'nginx', 'Date': 'Sun, 03 Nov 2024 20:58:49 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-dns-prefetch-control': 'off', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload', 'x-download-options': 'noopen', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block', 'request-id': '2992795c45bc6abd', 'vary': 'Origin, Accept-Encoding', 'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true', 'etag': 'W/"86-5CR7ttxfAA9VBRki4F937nxFYpM"', 'response-time': '29.876ms', 'content-encoding': 'gzip', 'ratelimit-value': '600', 'ratelimit-remaining': '599', 'x-request-id': 'ec507692-958e-4de5-94b9-6a86e3ee64a7'}
Response Body: {"status":500,"type":"","id":"2992795c45bc6abd","title":"Internal Server Error","detail":"Cannot convert undefined or null to object"}
API request failed: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: https://developer.api.autodesk.com/construction/admin/v2/projects/{project_id_here}/users:import
Error details: {"status":500,"type":"","id":"2992795c45bc6abd","title":"Internal Server Error","detail":"Cannot convert undefined or null to object"}

Here is my request, again with sensitive values replaced with {} placeholders. The roleIds have been hard-coded from the doc in an attempt to circumvent the issue but this also did not work. The doc does not explain how the roleIds are obtained for a project that was just created and does not yet have any members:
URL: https://developer.api.autodesk.com/construction/admin/v2/projects/{project_id_here}/users:import
Headers: {
  "Authorization": "Bearer {token_here}",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "User-Id": "{user_id_for_two_legged_auth_here}"
}
Data: [
  {
    "email": "{admin_email_here}",
    "companyId": "{company_id_here}",
    "roleIds": [
      "287d5cc2-9008-462c-96e5-c9491db85d97",
      "cda845af-05f0-4c46-9108-71b993946c35",
      "b8e84a73-7506-4d3f-b221-93691df2a359"
    ],
    "products": [
      {
        "key": "takeoff",
        "access": "member"
      },
      {
        "key": "projectAdministration ",
        "access": "administrator"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "email": "{user_email_here}",
    "companyId": "{company_id_here}",
    "roleIds": [
      "287d5cc2-9008-462c-96e5-c9491db85d97",
      "cda845af-05f0-4c46-9108-71b993946c35",
      "b8e84a73-7506-4d3f-b221-93691df2a359"
    ],
    "products": [
      {
        "key": "takeoff",
        "access": "member"
      },
      {
        "key": "projectAdministration ",
        "access": "none"
      }
    ]
  }
]

I am expecting a 200 response, but am getting the 500 response as noted above.

UPDATE:
I found another ACC link (https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/admin-v2-projects-project-Id-users-import-POST/) which actually leads to this API call and it includes more fields that that other ACC link I posted does not include, so Autodesk just hasn't updated that other doc yet.
This API call worked and returns a jobId like it should, but the change (the added users) are never reflected in the ACC project I added them to over 24 hours ago. So there may be something else about this endpoint that is also not stated in the docs.

I tried your request and replaced the email, company and roleids below and was successful, Kindly check your body again.
{
"users": [
    {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "email": "{admin_email_here}",
        "companyId": "{company_id_here}",
        "companyName": "",
        "roleIds": [
            "287d5cc2-9008-462c-96e5-c9491db85d97",
            "cda845af-05f0-4c46-9108-71b993946c35",
            "b8e84a73-7506-4d3f-b221-93691df2a359"
        ],
        "products": [
            {
                "key": "docs",
                "access": "administrator"
            },
            {
                "key": "takeoff",
                "access": "administrator"
            },
            {
                "key": "designCollaboration",
                "access": "none"
            },
            {
                "key": "modelCoordination",
                "access": "none"
            },
            {
                "key": "build",
                "access": "none"
            },
            {
                "key": "cost",
                "access": "none"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Jane",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "email": "{user_email_here}",
        "companyId": "{company_id_here}",
        "companyName": "",
        "roleIds": [
            "287d5cc2-9008-462c-96e5-c9491db85d97",
            "cda845af-05f0-4c46-9108-71b993946c35",
            "b8e84a73-7506-4d3f-b221-93691df2a359"
        ],
        "products": [
            {
                "key": "docs",
                "access": "administrator"
            },
            {
                "key": "takeoff",
                "access": "administrator"
            },
            {
                "key": "designCollaboration",
                "access": "none"
            },
            {
                "key": "modelCoordination",
                "access": "none"
            },
            {
                "key": "build",
                "access": "none"
            },
            {
                "key": "cost",
                "access": "none"
            }
        ]
    }
]

}

please see this other post link where this endpoint works but does nothing in ACC. There amy be something else about setting up projects in ACC that affects the success of this users:import endpoint which is not mentioned in the docs or does not have error handling setup.
